# Error returning 1 when comparing strings

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Can anyone tell me why Visual Studio is giving me an error when I try to return 1 by using my define ERROR macro? VS says its expecting a bracket :/

```
#define ERROR "A generic error has occured";

const char *RetAdapters(int *adapters) {

    if(...) {} 

    else
        return ERROR;
} 


int main()
{
    const char *ret = RetAdapters(&input);

    if (strcmp(*ret, ERROR) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of `ERROR` contains a trailing `;` which causes a syntax error when `ERROR` gets expanded in `if (strcmp(*ret, ERROR) == 0) {`

Remove the `;` from the macro definition and also remove the indirection `*`:

```
#define ERROR "A generic error has occurred"

const char *RetAdapters(int *adapters) {
    if (...) {
        ... 
    } else {
        return ERROR;
    }
} 

int main() {
    const char *ret = RetAdapters(&input);

    if (strcmp(ret, ERROR) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that this programming style is not recommended:

- `ERROR` could be defined as a global variable:

  ```
  const char ERROR[] = "A generic error has occurred";
  ```
- `RetAdapters()` could return a error status, different from `0` and return `0` for success. This is how most system calls report success and failure on unix systems, and this is how `main()` is supposed to report successful operation to the system.

Comment: "defining" string by macro in 2018 is terrible. Remeber `const` declarations are available since 20 years

Comment: @JacekCz: I am not advocating this programming style at all, merely correcting the bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `;` from your macro declaration

And in your strcmp remove the `*` because you are passing a char as parameter

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator
for more informations about this ;)

Comment: macro is not "definition"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion modern C/C++ code should define string constants like here (agree, identifier should be converted to lowercase by common C rules. f.e. `Error_msg` )

```
const char ERROR[]= "A generic error has occured";
```

every next problem are smooth contolled by compiler in type-safe manner

```
const char *RetAdapters(int *adapters) {

    if(...) {} 

    else
        return ERROR;
}
```

and

```
if (strcmp(ret, ERROR) == 0) { ...
```

UPDATE: few philosophical question exists about copying, comparing C strings (etc), but I assume out of subject.

Comment: what philosophical questions :) ?

Comment: Yorick skull to hand and " to copy, or not to copy, that is the question" :) And then allocate or not, compare strings or references ... time to switch to C++ (old C programmer say)